# ImageResizer - OutOfMemoryException for free edition

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I'm use ImageResizer in Asp.net application and from time to time I see `OutOfMemoryException`. The C# code is pretty simple:

```
var instruction = new Instructions { Width = width, 
                                     Height = height, 
                                     Format = null, 
                                     Mode = FitMode.Max }
(new ImageJob(source, destination, instruction)).Build();
```

The computer memory is used in 10% only and I don't see memory problems in monitoring tool. Here part of debugging log:

```
 Diagnostics for ImageResizer 4.1.10 ab91afb7 at  generated 1/20/2018 12:02:11 AM
Please remember to provide this page when contacting support.

You are using ImageResizer Essential Edition plugins.

2 issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.


(Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
            Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use

.....                        

When fetching a remote license file (if you have one), the following information is sent via the querystring.
```

I see the line `When fetching a remote license file (if you have one), the following information`. Maybe I need to upgrade to enterprise version?

Comment: OutOfMemoryException can be caused by not having a contiguous span of available memory to fit the data, it is not exactly related to system memory. It seems unlikely that the free version would cause a problem that the paid version does not. Make sure your you clean up disposable resources.

Comment: Please include more code that shows what source and destination are.

Comment: Also, are you running in 64-bit mode? I can't tell as you truncated the diagnostics page.

Comment: Yes, 64. What part of diagnostic do you need? It's too long to post it here.

Comment: Use gist.github.com